# ASP.NET MVC: Why request is being caught by the wrong method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using to wrap my forms the following helper:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController", FormMethod.Post)) { ... }
```

In my Controller I have two methods, one for loading my partial view and another one for processing the Post request:

```
    [SomeFilter]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public PartialViewResult Edit(int id)
    {
       //Some Code
    }

    [SomeFilter]        
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel model, string submit) {
       //Some Code
    }
```

Everything seems to be working fine except when users submit an empty form. In that case request is being caught by GET Method instead of POST one. I know it's calling the GET method because I get an exception as:

"The action 'Edit' is accessible only by a child request."

And only the GET overload has [ChildActionOnly] filter. I don't understand why is this happening. Both are different and both are decorated.

Any suggestions?

**Partial View code:**

```
@model MVC.Models.MyViewModel 

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

   <div class="row margin-top-20 form-group text-center">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-offset-2">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ManyItemsAvailable)
         @Html.ListBox("ManyItemsAvailable", Model.ItemsAvailable)
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value=">" id="add" name="submit" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default margin-top-10" value="<" id="remove" name="submit" />
      <div class="col-md-3">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ManyItemsSelected)
         @Html.ListBox("ManyItemsSelected", Model.ItemsSelected)
      </div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its not just being called on form reload? I would debug it from the browser and see at what point the server is called and match that with what is being sent from the browser?

Comment: It's not @Igor, I've a couple of breakpoints and it throws an exception as soon as I click on submit, never gets to the controller because it's getting in the ChildActionOnly filter.

Comment: Can you post your razor view?

Comment: @StephenZeng there it is.

Comment: The problem is `name="submit"` - change it to anything else (say) `name="action"` (and adjust the POST method parameter to match)

Answer (score 0):

So, I replaced both submit buttons with these:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value=">" id="add" name="submit" />
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default margin-top-10" value="<" id="remove" name="submit" formmethod="post" />
```

Explicitly specifying formmethod="post" and it's now working as expected.